# I am Searching Records using action suport onchange event but page is not refresh

Tags: apex

```
public class usingOnChangeFunction {
    Public List<Account> acc{set;get;}
    Public List<Account> acclist{set;get;}
    Public String aname{set;get;}
    Public usingOnChangeFunction(){
        acc=[select id,name,phone,industry from Account];

    }
    Public void searchrecord(){
        string searchquery='select id,name,phone,industry from Account where name like \'%'+aname+'%\' limit 20 ';
             acc=Database.query(searchquery);

    }
}
```

//vf code//

```
<apex:page controller="usingOnChangeFunction" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Searching"> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!aname}" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!searchrecord}" reRender="pb" />
        </apex:inputText>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details" id="pb"  > 

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a"  >
        <apex:column value="{!a.id}" />
        <apex:column value="{!a.name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.phone}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.industry}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page controller="usingOnChangeFunction" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form id="frmId">
        <apex:outputPanel >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Searching"> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!aname}" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!searchrecord}" reRender="frmId" />
        </apex:inputText>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Details" id="pb"  > 

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a"  >
        <apex:column value="{!a.id}" />
        <apex:column value="{!a.name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.phone}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.industry}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

try do something like this